# Sync clock with external server

Tags: windows, vba, ntp

**I want to sync my Windows clock with a clock of a certain Web Server which is not mine to a matters of miliseconds. How to get about doing this?**

Why? Because this is a auction server and I want to place my bid at the very last moment e.g. 100 miliseconds before closure.

What have I tried?:
Biding and checking the time of my bid. But the bid server shows the time with a 1 second precision and this is no good enough for me.

I am fluent with most languages/environments e.g. C#, VBA, Java, Windows, UNIX etc. so almost any solution will do.

Comment: Less your target server is an *Network Time Protocol* (NTP) server, or explicitly exposes some custom programatic interface you are out of luck.

Comment: What if knew if it was running IIS or Apache etc.? One of my ideas was generating some server error that would send me the error time or something.

Comment: I would be very surprise if any publicly available error message contained a more precise timestamp (and time to generate such an error is likely to incur random variation greater than you're target precision).

Comment: I doubt that this error approach will give you the `matters of miliseconds` precision that you ask for. In addition, whoever runs this machine is probably not going to like this...

Comment: Thanks Richard. Yeah but if I could get anywhere near < 1 second would be fantastic.

Comment: is it on a website? scrape and predict maybe?

Comment: That's what I did with the bid. But the precision is 1 second. Any ideas to get below that?

Comment: Thanks reto. I am not concerned with the owner of this machine as this is not ebay or anything. The bidding process is written by some amateur developer and the web form is dead simple. Another idea that I have now is to simply bid small amounts in short intervals before when I know there is about 1 sec for closure.